# If 3^1993 =100k + n, where n < 100 is a nonnegative integer, what is n?

Tags: contest-math

If 3^1993 =100k + n, where n < 100 is a non-negative integer, what is n?

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Note that $3^m\pmod {100}$ is periodic as a function of $m$.

Comment: $1993 \equiv -7 \pmod{40}$ so $3^{1993} \equiv \frac{1}{3^7} \equiv \frac{1}{2187} \equiv -\frac{1}{13} \equiv -\frac{1001}{13}\equiv-77\equiv23 \pmod{100}$

Comment: @Evariste How did you get 1993≡−7(mod40)

Comment: Worth remarking:  it may be easier to solve the problem $\pmod {4}$ and $\pmod {25}$ and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @VSPuzzler $3$ and $100$ are coprime so $3^{\varphi(100)} = 3^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, so this allows reducing the exponent. To get $-7$, notice that e.g. $25 \times 40 = 1000$

Comment: @lulu How do I use mod 4 and mod 25 to do this?

Comment: @Evariste Is there a theorem that says that if two numbers are coprime that gives you that?

Comment: @VSPuzzler Euler's theorem

Comment: Solve the problem for remainders $\pmod 4$ and $\pmod {25}$, then use the CRT to find the unique remainder $\pmod {100}$ that matches those solutions.  $4$ is effortless.  $25$ takes a minute.

Comment: @lulu Do I just multiply the two remainders?

Comment: Of course not.  You should read about the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  It's one of the most important tools in arithmetic.

Comment: $3^{20}\equiv1\bmod1000$ by [Carmichael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), so $3^{1993}\equiv3^{13}\equiv3\cdot9^6$ $\equiv3\cdot(10-1)^6$ $\equiv3\cdot(1-6\cdot10)=3-180=-177\equiv23\bmod100$

Comment: @Evariste How did you get 3^40? Why did you choose 40?

Comment: @VSPuzzler:  $40$ is the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(100)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that a cycle appears, $03,09,27,81,43,29,87,61,83,49,47,41,23,69,07,21,63,89,67,01,03...$
Cycle length of 20.

Another thing to notice is that $3^{100}$ mod 100 = 1.

Comment: Would there be an easier way to go about this without going through each value? Thanks

Comment: @VSPuzzler Use $\varphi(100)=40$ so you know it's at least periodic a divisor of $40$. The exponent reduces to $-7$ either way, then check my comment.